# How to prepare a build job that produces .dll and unix .so on single Windows environment?

Tags: c++, c, dll, build, shared-libraries

How to create a C++ single build job that will produce .dll working on windows and .so prepared to work on Unix?

Suppose that our development environment is based on Windows.

Comment: Does your code compile on Linux already, or are you looking for a tool that can make your Windows code run on Linux without a porting effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some simple solution. Please just consider this as a idea. I have never done this. but I think logically this should be possible.

1. Start your work in windows environment.
2. You have to write the code that should support windows and Unix by using Pre-processor directives.
3. create two make files that support for windows and Unix (make_win, make_uni). Actually you can do this in a single make file too.
4. Install Oracle [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) in windows environment.
5. install [fedora-18](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora) on virtual box.
6. Now you can access your make files by windows and Fedora both OSs concurrently (simply you can access same file system using two OSs ).
7. Run make_win using windows and run make_uni using fedora.

Note: you can chose to work in Linux environment and possible to install virtual-box and windows top on that.

these things may help you 
http://geekery.amhill.net/2010/01/27/virtualbox-with-existing-windows-partition/
http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/04/09/virtualbox-access-windows-host-shared-folders-from-ubuntu-guest/

Answer (score 2):

On Unix or Linux your shared library would need to link against system libraries like `/lib64/libc.so.6` and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. There is no way to link against these on Windows, if that is what you are asking (unless you deployed a Linux cross-compile toolchain on Windows, if that exists). You would need to compile it on the target operating system.

Comment: Very good point, i have thought about virtual machine solution, but really dosen't know origins what this is such big problem

Answer (score 0):

use minGW and prepare your code for linux and windows

http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: I viewed binary .so file produced by `g++ --shared a.cpp -o a.so` and it contains for example "stdarg.h   windef.h   stddef.h   winnt.h   stdio.h", so this is a .dll renamed to .so, I am right?

Comment: I know that it's possible the other way round, using a linux host system and cross compile for windows using GCC + MinGw. I don't know if there's a toolchain available to cross compile a linux .so on a windows host system (I'd doubt that).

Answer (score 0):

May be Cygwin environment allows some cross compiling tricks: [Cross compiling for linux from Cygwin](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html)

Didn't test this myself, but could imagine some build process that splits up for e.g. MinGw to build the Windows .dll and Cygwin and this cross compile tool for the .so ...

It could turn out (depending on your real use case) that simply using a VM to compile on a Linux/Unix system and share the pure source code for compiling (e.g. using CMake + GCC + MinGw [for Windows only] as unified build environment, or even cross compile the Windows .dll from the linux system) serves you better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CMake can do this :)
You'll need to develop the skills of writing decent cmake rules but when you master it you can easily cross build with one small build command. Also I'd recommend using Jenkins with your CMake, this can be linked with CTest and CPack and you'll have an awesome development dungeon :)

Comment: Even CMake cannot compile for linux without a suitable crosscompiler under windows. You can use CMake to create a build environment that works properly on either platform linux and windows. But that wasn't the OPs question, right?

Comment: Well I use CMake and gcc to crossbuild Windows and Linux code on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

Rework on Source code ,must be needed. Also if MinGW is used, we can minimize the rework.But if we use Microsoft compiler, rework is more and have to use separate make file.